# implement on scroll to load data

Tags: android, arrays, json, scrollview

This is my tryout please tell me how to load data in on scroll 
I am using `onScrollStateChanged` but its not working for me.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lvls = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
   lvls.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener());
}

class EndlessScrollListener implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                         int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        GallaryLoad();
    }


public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
@Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return array_bean.size();
    }
@Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }
@Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                        ViewGroup parent) {
                if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_reader, null);
        }
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.reader_thumbnail);
        TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.reader_title);
        TextView reader_categories = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.reader_categories);
          Picasso
                .with(MainActivity.this)
                .load("http://it-tips.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/primefactors.png")
                .transform(new RoundedCornersTransformation(15, 1,
                        RoundedCornersTransformation.CornerType.TOP))
                .placeholder(R.drawable.progress_animation)
                .into(imageView);


        textView.setText(array_bean.get(position).getTitle());
        reader_categories.setText(array_bean.get(position).getCategories());
        return convertView;
    }
}
private void GallaryLoad() {
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonObject = response.getJSONArray("posts");
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonObject.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject object1 = jsonObject.getJSONObject(i);
                            PostItem info = new PostItem();
                            info.setTitle(object1.getString("title"));
                            info.setCategories(object1.getString("slug"));
 info.setImgUrl(object1.getString("url"));

                            array_bean.add(info);
                            lvls.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter());
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    });
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

I am new android developer but cant understand how to put in my list view ill see so many tutorial but  i cant understand so please help me to load data with scroll

thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
list.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            if (list.getLastVisiblePosition() == -1) {
            } else if (list.getLastVisiblePosition() == (skip - 1) && !isLoading) {
                isLoading = true;
                getParticipant();
            }
        }
    });
```

Update skip(with no. of data loaded) and isLoading(make it false) in response callback. You can pass this skip to your network call so that they provide data next to this number.

```
list.getLastVisiblePosition() means nothing is visible.
```

Comment: how to `notifydatasetchanged` in base adapter please jest tell me

Comment: What are `skip` and `isLoading`, `getParticipant` do or for?

Comment: skip is used to keep the count of data we have loaded(ex. 20 out of 200 we have so when user scrolls to 19th item we have it hit service again to get next 20 and skip will be 40 now) and getParticipant is you method call to fetch data.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a `RecyclerView` for your purpose.
2. Implement the RecyclerView.Adapter
3. in `bindViewHolder(VH holder, int position)` determine the last position on which you want to reload data
4. reload data if position is > x, where x is your position to reload data, usally you want to reload when x == `getItemCount()`
5. apply `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the Adapter

There are plenty tutorials for RecyclerView out there. 
A good start is
[Creating list and Cards](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)

[See RecyclerView.Adapter Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html)

Comment: how to `notifydatasetchanged` in base adapter please jest tell me

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged() and the methods below. Call this, once you have added more data to the adapters dataset. If we're assuming yo're using the recycler view approach.